# How to get computer hardware infomation by MQL5, such su device ID, serial No

Tags: mql5

I want to get the computer device inforation by MQL5, such us Device ID, serial No.,computer name, etc. i was searching in the internet, finded the hint by importing DLL, kernel32.dll. but failed to access the infomation I want. hope experienced persons can help me.

Thank you very much.

#import "kernel32.dll"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

> #import "Kernel32.dll" int GetComputerNameW(short& lpBuffer[], uint& lpnSize); int GetComputerNameA(char& lpBuffer[], uint& lpnSize);
> #import
>
> #define MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH 1024+1
>
> string GetComputerNameW()   {    ushort
> buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH];    uint size =
> MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH-1;    GetComputerNameW(buffer, size);
>
> string computerName = ShortArrayToString(buffer);
>
> return (computerName);   }
>
> string GetComputerNameA()   {    uchar
> buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH];    uint size =
> MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH-1;    GetComputerNameA(buffer, size);
>
> string computerName = CharArrayToString(buffer);
>
> return (computerName);   }